# What is the difference between a Marshmallow field defined with `data_key` and one defined with `attribute` (with the identifiers reversed?)

Tags: python, attributes, schema, marshmallow

Is there a difference between a `marshmallow.Schema` (v3.0+) where a field with name `foo` is defined with `attribute="bar"`, and another where a field with name `bar` is defined with `data_key="foo"`?

Both seem to serialize and deserialize dictionaries and other simple objects in the same way:

```
import marshmallow

class MySchema1(marshmallow.Schema):
    foo = marshmallow.fields.String(attribute="bar")

class MySchema2(marshmallow.Schema):
    bar = marshmallow.fields.String(data_key="foo")

schema1 = MySchema1()
schema2 = MySchema2()

dictionary = {"bar": "hello world"}
assert schema1.dump(dictionary) == schema2.dump(dictionary)
assert schema1.load(schema1.dump(dictionary)) == schema2.load(schema2.dump(dictionary))

class Thingy:
    def __init__(self):
        self.bar = "hello world"

instance = Thingy()
assert schema1.dump(instance) == schema2.dump(instance)
assert schema1.load(schema1.dump(instance)) == schema2.load(schema2.dump(instance))
```

The above passes. This isn't causing any errors in my project currently, but I am curious what the difference is! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are right. Both schemas behave identically.

This could be seen as redundant API: from your example, you could wonder why have `attribute` if `data_key` provides the same functionality.

In practice, it is useful to have both, because it allows to specify keys that are invalid python variable names for both load and dump keys.

```
class MySchema(marshmallow.Schema):
    foo = marshmallow.fields.String(attribute="bar-load", data_key="bar-dump")
```

AFAIK, this is the reason we didn't drop `attribute` in marshmallow. There may be other reasons, but this one seems like a good one already.

Comment: I was unable to until a moment ago (when I breached 15 reputation.) Cheers!